# How would colonists from the Outer Solar System see UNAPA?

Tags: internal-consistency, humans, hard-science, politics, history

As you can tell, I had a question as to who was the bigger monster in the Extraplanetary Wars. However, that question is currently on hold, but I shall link regardless: [The Extraplanetary Wars: Which is the Bigger Monster?](https://www.reddit.com/r/worldbuilding/comments/4f8bgn/in_this_situation_which_side_is_the_bigger_monster/) Still, I had some concerns about how the colonists on the Outer Solar System, on Mars and even on Earth and her remaining loyal colonies might see each other. Mars during both wars was fought via an insurgency. In the first war, the insurgents lost and those that reintegrated into society had their descendants become members of the renewed insurgency. However, it was mainly the focus of the struggle between Earth and the colonies of the Outer Solar System (and the colonies against each other). So, the first of these questions is: how would the colonists of the Outer Solar System see UNAPA by 2500?

NOTE: The 52 km/s speed was the asteroid's final speed at the time of collision (i.e. at its perihelion after being redirected, and since the majority of the asteroid's mass was used up to move the bloody thing, the asteroid which was originally 2 km is now ~985 metres in diameter).

Comment: @XandarTheZenon Er.....I never said they would ALLOW such death to happen! But I suppose that is one interpretation.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon I can save that for a different question. For now, time to focus on Earth and the Outer Solar System colonists (aka: the non-Martian/Lunar/Venusian/Mercurian colonists). :P

Comment: :( I'll delete my comments and save them for later on my iPad. I will be watching for that one. I think this could best be three questions, the colonies conquered, the ones not yet reached or on the edge of losing, and the inner solar system. That is probably what you planned though. I think your ideas are pretty good, I'd be interested to read this story.

Comment: Please clarify: the asteroid attack was the single largest instance of human genocide in the history of your setting?

Comment: @ScottDowney Not necessarily. There have been other genocides, none explained in detail, but all I can say is that during both conflicts, whole Belt settlements and Trojan colonies have been destroyed by both sides. The asteroid one is just the big one. (Mainly due to the long-term casualties with 20% of the world's population dead).

Comment: [tag:hard-science] should not be included in this question. [tag:reality-check] is also misplaced. Read the tag descriptions by clicking on the links. Try to scope your questions and decide what tags accurately describe your question - tags, in short, help tell us what you are asking.

Comment: @FutureHistorian And consider this; how can we figure out what people would think? Of course their opinion of the UNAPA will likely be negative overall due to the constant war. Other than that you can shape opinions however you want.